# Can't get hebrew wikipedia abstract from DBPedia

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I'm attempting to use DBPedia to retrieve wikipedia article abstracts in several languages, one of them is in Hebrew, I'm getting a result row for the English language but not for Hebrew.

```
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?name ?abstract WHERE {
     ?name <http://dbpedia.org/property/viaf> 113230702 .
     ?name ontology:abstract ?abstract
     FILTER (LANG(?abstract)='en')
}
```

[Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20ontology%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20property%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fname%20%3Fabstract%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2Fviaf%3E%20113230702%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20ontology%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28%3Fabstract%29%3D%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

(the query returned article abstract for authors with a certain [VIAF id](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/viafId))

When I change `'en'` (line 7) to `'he'` I get nothing. when I removed the `FILTER` line I got a result set of only several languages.

How do I access or query for more languages data such as in hebrew ?

Answer (score 1):

The way language tags work is that the data needs to assert a string with the language tag.  There isn't any language processing going on in the background. When you take the FILTER statement out, then those are the languages that DBPedia has for the matches it found for ?abstract.

In your case, the data just doesn't have any `'he'` language tags.  To see what language tags are found, try the following query:

```
SELECT ?name ?abstract (LANG(?abstract) AS ?lang)
WHERE {
  ?name <http://dbpedia.org/property/viaf> 113230702 .
  ?name ontology:abstract ?abstract
}
```

Comment: I think i'm getting the same results that I got without `FILTER`

Comment: There is no Hebrew DBpedia: http://oldwiki.dbpedia.org/Internationalization/Chapters